# Slack conversation permanently attached to a Trello link when hit Attach Conversation

Tags: trello, slack, bot

We are using Slack & Trello to manage a project which has it's own Slack channel. In Trello we have a board that contains Lists for each of the stages in our process. We create a card for one stage and move it along the board to different lists as we advance in our workflow.

In slack I executed command:  /trello [link to my card] then hit "attach Conversation" button.  A URL was generated in Trello side as an attachment to my card.  That was fun and good to grab the conversation related to the card.

Then the conversation changed to other topics and suddenly we realized the complete conversation was saved in the same link, It's not stopping.

Even we removed the attachment and delete the card, the Trello link is still saving every word written in the Slack channel.

Any idea on how to stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link that Slack provided for you and is now used in Trello as an "attached conversation" is a link into the regular Slack Archives.

Slack generally archives all of your conversations and provides deep links to them. The link you received when you attached the conversation to a Trello card should point to the exact moment when the conversation happened (albeit in the context of a larger, full archive page).

At the moment, there is no way how you could stop this *particular* behaviour - it is intended this way. "Attach conversation" does nothing more than insert one link to the current place in the Slack channel conversation archive. It doesn't actually include or copy or otherwise save the conversation.

You *can* however change the message logging in Slack itself: see https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/203457187-Custom-message-and-file-retention for this.

Comment: Very nice explanation, now I understand a little bit better how slack works on this matter, thanks !